# Invoking Blackberry Map application with address details

Tags: blackberry, gps, location, launch

I am working with version 4.6 of the blackberry OS.

I am attempting to invoke the Maps application using the following:

```
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS, new MapsArguments(MapsArguments.ARG_LOCATION_DOCUMENT, document));
```

This works fine for an example document such as:

```
            String document = "<lbs>" + "<location lon='-8030000' lat='4326000' label='Kitchener, ON' description='Kitchener, Ontario, Canada' />" + "</lbs>";
```

My question is: how can I construct such a document if I do not know the coordinates of the location I am trying to inspect? I only know the address...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this document](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17954/XML_element_location_893142_11.jsp), <location> supports an address, city, postal code, and region attributes. Would this work?

If that doesn't work, you'll need to use the [Locator](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/Locator.html) class to get the location information. It needs starting coordinates though. Code from page 25 of the [documentation](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/5785/GPS_and_BlackBerry_Maps-4.6.1-US.pdf):

```
// Create an javax.microedition.location.AddressInfo  object
AddressInfo ai = new AddressInfo();

// Set the fields of the AddressInfo Object
ai.setField(AddressInfo.STREET, “main street”);
ai.setField(AddressInfo.CITY, “Toronto”);
ai.setField(AddressInfo.STATE, “Ontario”);
ai.setField(AddressInfo.POSTAL_CODE, “XXX XXX”);
ai.setField(AddressInfo.COUNTRY, “Canada”);

// Create a Coordinates object that the location-based services locator server
//   uses as a starting location to search for location 
//   information for an address.
Coordinates co = new Coordinates(45.423488, -75.697929, 0);

// Create a Locator object.
Locator lo = new Locator();

// Invoke Locator.geocode(AddressInfo address, Coordinates startCoords).
Enumeration en = lo.geocode(ai, co);
```

Comment: This works great - thanks for pointing me towards the correct documentation.